# How to show bluetooth connected icon in Android when connected via RFCOMM socket

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm, spp

I'm building an android app that connects to another android app via bluetooth, using the serial port profile (SPP, UUID=00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB).

I'm able to successfully connect from the client (via a BluetoothSocket using CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()) to the server (listening via ListenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord()), however the bluetooth icon in the notification bar does not show the "connected" bluetooth icon like it does when I connect a bluetooth headset, or other similar device (the "connected" and "disconnected" icons that I expect to see are below).

Why does this icon not change to show that there is a device that is currently connected via bluetooth?

Connected:

[image: Connected Bluetooth Icon]

Disconnected:

[image: Disconnected Bluetooth Icon]

Comment: i guess it is not possible as rfcomm socket connection is done by the applciations where as headset connections is done by system settings app. Since the notification is updated by system app, it is not possible for 3rd party apps to access the same notification and update. Best things to maintain your own notification icon.

Comment: This seems like an oversight. What's the difference if the connection is maintained by the system or by an app? From a user's perspective, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Exactly, there shouldn't be any differece, However, AFAIK it is not possible to update system notifications by 3rd party apps.